# Using Preg_replace for "..."

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace all the "..." with preg_replace,
Example : Hello... => Hello

I tryed with  :

```
$dir = preg_replace('/.../', '', $dir);
```

But it doesn't work :/

Comment: Why are you using `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [dot](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php) (`.`) is a special character in regular expressions which matches any single character except a newline (or any character at all if `PCRE_DOTALL` is specified). If you really want to match a literal `.` character you'd have to escape it or wrap it in a character class.

However, for something this simple, there's no need for regular expressions. Just use [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$dir = str_replace('...', '', $dir);
```

Also note, that a [horizontal ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) (`…`) is a separate Unicode character from three periods (`...`). If you need to handle these as well, it gets kind of tricky since PHP doesn't offer true Unicode support. Exactly how you handle it depends on the encoding of `$dir`, but assuming it's UTF-8 encoded, this will remove any horizontal ellipsis characters (`\xE2\x80\xA6` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `\u2026`):

```
$dir = str_replace("\xE2\x80\xA6", '', $dir);
```